# How to deleting files depending on their usage?

Tags: scripts

How can I use a script in order to delete files according to how much I using them?

There are a large amount of files under a directory. I would like to preserve such files which I use (open) very often. I would like to delete those, which I did not use in a certain period.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the timestamp property on the files in question. I'd recommend writing a simple script in bash something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls -1 *.log`
  do
    myfile=`ls -l $i | awk '{print $6,$7,$9}'`
    if [[ ${myfile% *} = 'Jan 1' ]];
    then
      echo "Removing ${myfile##* }"
      #rm ${myfile##* }
    else
      echo "Failed to remove file ${myfile##* }"
    fi
done
```

Give it a try. If this script gives you what you're looking for, then just remove the "#" character in front of the RM command to perform the deletion operation.

Comment: Thank you. What is $6, $7, $9 mean?

Comment: They represent columns of data. In this case, the 6th, 7th and 9th column of the output of the 'ls' command. Here's a link that might help for reference: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/awk-introduction-tutorial-7-awk-print-examples/

Comment: Why not just use `find ... -ctime ...` as @PrathuBaronia suggest below ?

Comment: Downvoted since it parses `ls` command. This is a bad practice. Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to delete the files that were last modified 7 or more days back.

```
find <directory path> -ctime +7 -delete
```